# Filter an array by checking the content of another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have two arrays with the following structures:

```
const array1 = [{id: 1, name: "test"}, {id: 2, name: "test2"}, {id: 3, name: "test3"}];
const array2 = [{weight: 1, ids: [1]}, {weight 3, ids: [3]}];
```

I want to filter `array1` so that it only has items where the id does not exists within any of the ids arrays within array 2.

I tried the following:

```
array1.filter((item) =>
      !array1?.filter((item2) =>
        item2?.ids?.includes(item.id)
      )
    )
```

however it just returns an empty array.

Can anyone provide me with the correct way of doing this filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to find in array2 instead of filter array1

```
array1.filter((item)=>
!array2.find((item2)=>item2?.ids?.includes(items.id))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array.every() to filter your array.

```js
const array1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'test' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3' },
];
const array2 = [
  { weight: 1, ids: [1] },
  { weight: 3, ids: [3] },
];

const res = array1.filter((item1) =>
  array2.every((item2) => !item2.ids.includes(item1.id))
);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flat `array2` into a single array,and then use filter on `array1`

```js
const array1 = [{id: 1, name: "test"}, {id: 2, name: "test2"}, {id: 3, name: "test3"}];
const array2 = [{weight: 1, ids: [1]}, {weight:3, ids: [3]}];

let filters = array2.map(a => a.ids).flat()
let result = array1.filter(a => {
  return !filters.includes(a.id)
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` return a list where the callback return true and `find` return a item where the callback return true

```js
array1.filter(({id})=>{
  return array2.find(({ids})=>ids.indexOf(id) == -1) == null
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a map that stores all the different `ids` from `array2`

```
const array1 = [{id: 1, name: "test"}, {id: 2, name: "test2"}, {id: 3, name: "test3"}];
const array2 = [{weight: 1, ids: [2]}, {weight: 3, ids: [2]}];
const temp = array2.reduce((prev, {ids}) => {
    ids.forEach(id => {
        if(!prev.has(id)) {
            prev.set(id, true);
        }
    })
    return prev;
}, (new Map()));
```

Now filter from `array1` based on the `id` not present in the `map`.

```
const ans = array1.filter(({id}) => !temp.has(id));
console.log(ans)
```

With map you will have better time complexity than what will be with array. (generally, add, delete, search all happen in O(1) with map)

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of a Map, the `Set` might be a better aggregator for keeping the list of existing ids. Set by default make the existing Ids list unique and `Set.has` method can be used to check if the id of the item from array1 exists in array2.

```js
const existingIds = array2.reduce((list,item)=> {
   list = new Set([...list, ...item.ids])
   return list;
}, new Set())

array1.filter( ({id}) => !existingIds.has(id))
```

Benefits:

- existingIds is Set so it will have each id only once.
- Set.has a time complexity of O(1)
- Total solution will have O(n) complexity